# GCC finding errors in MinGW's stdio.h

Tags: c, gcc, mingw, winpcap

I'm trying to compile some [example C code](https://www.winpcap.org/docs/docs_411/html/group__wpcap__tut1.html) with GCC/MinGW on Windows 7. The example code includes some local header files which ultimately include stdio.h, and I get this error when I try to compile:

```
c:\mingw\include\stdio.h:345:12: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '__mingw__snprintf'
extern int __mingw_stdio_redirect__(snprintf)(char*, size_t, const char*, ...);
```

This is a weird one to me. How could there possibly be errors in stdio.h?

Comment: There could be something in a file included before "stdio.h" that confuses the compiler. Do you still get the error if you try to compile just one file that includes "stdio.h" first?

Comment: Please post the contents of the header file `pcap.h`  Please do NOT post links to code, rather copy/paste the code into your question

Comment: there are only two valid signatures for `main()`  they are: `int main( void )` and `int main( int argc, char *argv[] )`

Comment: Please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it

Comment: @user3629249: the file `pcap.h` (and, for that matter, the sample code) are part of the winpcap code bundle, not the work of OP. So your comment about main prototypes is not as well-directed as it could be.

Answer (score 0):

regarding:

```
if (i == 0)
{
    printf("\nNo interfaces found! Make sure WinPcap is installed.\n");
    return 0;
}  
pcap_freealldevs(alldevs);
```

since the variable `i` is initialized to 0 and never modified, this `if()` statement will always be `true`.  One result is the call to: `pcap_freealldev()` will never be called.

the `scope` of variables should be limited as much as reasonable.

Code should never depend on the OS to clean up after itself.  suggest

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "pcap.h"

int main( void )
{
    pcap_if_t *alldevs = NULL;
    char errbuf[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];

    /* Retrieve the device list from the local machine */
    if (pcap_findalldevs_ex(PCAP_SRC_IF_STRING, NULL /* auth is not needed */, &alldevs, errbuf) == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Error in pcap_findalldevs_ex: %s\n", errbuf);
        exit(1);
    }

    /* Print the list */
    for( pcap_if_t *d = alldevs; d != NULL; d= d->next)
    {
        printf("%d. %s", ++i, d->name);
        if (d->description)
            printf(" (%s)\n", d->description);
        else
            printf(" (No description available)\n");
    }

    if ( ! alldevs )
    {
        printf("\nNo interfaces found! Make sure WinPcap is installed.\n");
    }

    /* We don't need any more the device list. Free it */
    pcap_freealldevs(alldevs);
}
```

Comment: `i` is modified at line 20 ( `printf("%d. %s", ++i, d->name);` ) which executes for each device found. Presumably, the winpcap folks (*not* OP) thought it was pointless freeing all devs if no device was found. In any case, this answer is irrelevant to OP's question. (I agree that your test is better than their test, fwiw. But the effect is the same in the end.)